# Syntax for collecting data in var query

Tags: asp.net, database, var

I am collecting some data from database using var query and storing it in an integer. Below is the code:

```
var query1 = from meet_emp in db.Meet_Emps
             where meet_emp.Employee_ID == empid
             select meet_emp.Meeting_ID;

int meetNum = query1.First();
```

Here query1 contains multiple meeting ids. I wish to store all id's into an int variable or int array as I would be using each meeting id later into another query. With syntax "int meetNum = query1.First()", I get only the first meeting id.

How do I get all the meeting id's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change to `ToList` then you will have a list of IDs

```
var query1 = from meet_emp in db.Meet_Emps
             where meet_emp.Employee_ID == empid
             select meet_emp.Meeting_ID;

var meetNum = query1.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks I wanted in an array so that I can use each element of it later... i used int[] meetid = query1.ToArray() and it worked...

Answer (score 1):

You can leave the data just as it is in variable `query1`, then join it later with your final query that uses that list:

```
from blah in db.Stuff
join query1 on query1.Meeting_ID equals blah.Meeting_ID
select ...;
```

Comment: +1. Or `from blah in db.Stuff where query1.Contains(blah.Meeting_ID) select...`